# Asynchronous request returning nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

i've made following Asynchronous request, the problem is that its empty i've tried in the bottom NSLog the fixtures where its empty. I've checked that the nsstring home, away, league and so on returns values and it does. How come the values are not added to the fixtures NSMutableArray

```
[ProgressHUD show:@"Loading..."];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"API_URL"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {

         jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];



         int subObjects = ((NSArray *)jsonResult[@"match"]).count;
         for (int i = 0; i <= subObjects-1; i++) {

             NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"playdate"] objectAtIndex:i], [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"time"] objectAtIndex:i]];
             NSString *identifier = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];

             NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             [df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Arizona"]];
             [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier]];
             [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

             NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date]];





             NSArray *items = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myDate] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


             NSString *home = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"hometeam"] objectAtIndex:i];
             NSString *away = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"awayteam"] objectAtIndex:i];
             NSString *league = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"league"] objectAtIndex:i];




             [fixtures addObject:
              [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
               items[0], @"date",
               items[1], @"time",
               home, @"home",
               away, @"away",
               league, @"league",
               nil]];

             [sections addObject:
              [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
               items[0], @"date",
               nil]];


         }


     }
 ];



[self.theTableView reloadData];

[ProgressHUD dismiss];

NSLog(@"%@", fixtures);
```

Comment: check initialization for fixtures (mutable array). better will be make it strong & initialize it in viewdidload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a non-blocking operation. It means that by calling this method it returns immediatelly while the actual request is performing somewhere in background and then calls the handler block on queue specified in `queue` parameter.
You should reload tableview from the completion-handler block.

```
// 1 before request
NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
// 3 request completed
// some processing
...
[self.theTableView reloadData];

[ProgressHUD dismiss];
}
// 2 immediate return
```

**update**

Although you passing the main queue as `queue` parameter the handler block will be performed on next run loop iteration after you reloading table and logging the values.

```
// current run loop iteration
NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
// next run loop iteration
}
// current run loop iteration
```

Comment: you dont read this line "NSLog the fixtures where its empty." . its written in completion handler. problem is with mutablearray.

Comment: @pawan the bottom `NSLog(@"%@", fixtures);` is outside the completion handler

Comment: One quick question. How can i make a progressHUD around the request. When i do this inside the completionhandler it does not seem to work.

Comment: @user3423384, you should call `show:` before sending a request and call `dismiss` at the end of completion handler. Do you still use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` as the `queue` parameter?

Comment: Yes i do :) Should i use anything else as queue parameter?

Comment: No, main queue is fine. So the HUD appears, table view reloads fine but at the end HUD is still on screen? Strange, did you try to remove all code except `dismiss` call from completion handler?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the request is an **asynchronous function**

If the function is asynchronous, the function will create another thread and return immediately to execute the next line after the one that invoked the asynchronous function. Meanwhile the new thread will execute some code and, eventually execute the block passed as parameter, and finally the thread is killed and doesn't exist any more.

This means that

```
NSLog(@"%@", fixtures);
```

will most likely be executed **before** the `sendAsynchronousRequest` has finished it's job, that's why it is returning `nil`.

Everything you need to do to process the downloaded information should happen inside the `completionHandler` block, including the call to `[self.theTableView reloadData];`

Comment: So thats why my tableview is not showing anything. So how can i print the fixtures array after asynchronous function is finished?

Comment: @user3423384 If you place the `NSLog(...)` **inside** the `completionHandler` block (at the end) you should see the results (I hope!)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!fixtures) {
    fixtures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[fixtures addObject:@{
    @"date": items[0],
    @"time": items[1],
    @"home": home,
    @"away": away,
    @"league": league
}];

if(!sections) {
    sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[sections addObject:@{
    @"date": items[0]
}];

[self.theTableView reloadData];

[ProgressHUD dismiss];

NSLog(@"%@", fixtures);
```